# How can I empty this AngularJS form after submitting the data?

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I am working on a **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **AngularJS v1.7.8**.

The *post comments form* is submitted via AngularJS. Here is the form:

```
<form name="commentForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="form-controll 6u 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="newComment.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true" />
            <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.name.$touched && commentForm.name.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.name.$invalid)">This field can not be empty</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-controll 6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="newComment.email" placeholder="Email" ng-required="true" />
            <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.email.$touched && commentForm.email.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.email.$invalid)">Enter a valid email address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-controll 12u$">
            <textarea name="comment" rows="6" id="message" ng-model="newComment.comment" placeholder="Comment" ng-required="true"></textarea>
            <span class="error" ng-show="(commentForm.comment.$touched && commentForm.comment.$invalid) || (commentForm.$submitted && commentForm.comment.$invalid)">This field can not be empty</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Break -->
        <div class="12u$">
            <input type="submit" value="Add comment" ng-click="createComment()" class="button special fit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the *AngularJS controller* that manages it's submission to the Codeigniter back-end:

```
 // Post comment
.controller('PostCommentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    const slug = $routeParams.slug;
    $http.get('api/' + slug).then(function(response) {

        let post_id = response.data.post.id

        $scope.newComment = {
            slug: $routeParams.slug,
            post_id: post_id,
            name: $scope.name,
            email: $scope.email,
            comment: $scope.comment
        };

        $scope.createComment = function(){
          $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment);
        };
    });
}])
```

I have not yet been able to find a way to *empty the form* and make it *pristine* after (and *only* after) the data it contains has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also set the form as *untouched*: `$scope.commentForm.$setUntouched()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$scope.createComment = function(){
  $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment)
    .then(() => {
       $scope.newComment = {
         slug: $routeParams.slug,
         post_id: '',
         name: '',
         email: '',
         comment: ''
      };
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you see a reason NOT to do this instead: `$http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment)
    .then(() => {
     $scope.newComment = {};
    });`?

Comment: It does. Both solutions work, yet both have this problem: the form gets empty but *not pristine*. In other words, the form appears as *invalid after successful submission*.

Comment: Can you try `$scope.commentForm.$setPristine()`?

Comment: I tryed `.then(() => {
     $scope.newComment = {};
     $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
    });` and it does not get pristine. It is submitting the data though. :)

Comment: The inputs do not loose "ng-invalid": `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="newComment.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true" class="ng-touched ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required">` after sucesfull submition.

Comment: Right, you will need also $scope.commentForm.$setUntouched()

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked:

```
$scope.createComment = function() {
    $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment)
        .then(() => {
            $scope.newComment = {};
            $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.commentForm.$setUntouched();
        });
};
```